# List View Formatting(json) - Conditional Message when there are no items on the list/view

Tags: list-view, json-formatting

I am using List View Formatting.
Is it possible to show a custom message "e.g Sorry no items on this list" when there are no item records? Instead of this default message that says something like "Welcome to your new list".

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible. I have requested it multiple times with the team, however. It's really needed.

Comment: THanks theChrisKent. Absolutely its a must to have. One other needed would be paging